# How to setup authorization on api-platform.com

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I'm trying to use api-platform.com as my API infrastructure. And I want to make sure that every user can pull his OWN data and perform actions on his data inly.

How can I do that?

Lets say that I have an entity named 'Organization' and 'Book'.
Book belongs to Organization on book.orgnization_id = organization.id.
In addition, the User entity belongs to organization using the same relation.

How can I do this authorization check?

Thanks!

Comment: if you want to fetch a single book you have to do a simple: has the book and the current user the same organization

Comment: Did you looked at https://api-platform.com/docs/core/security? The example is almost what you describe.

Comment: Please post the 'Organization' and 'Book' entity code.

Comment: More examples about authorization are described in chapter 8 of my [tutorial](https://github.com/metaclass-nl/tutorial-api-platform), the resulting code is in chapter 9.